# Using the stream insertion operator to read files

Tags: c++, file-io

I happened to run across a code example for reading text from a file as follows:

```
int i; 
char *fileName = "text.txt"; 
ifstream fin(fileName); 

while (fin >> i)
{
do something;
}
```

This code actually opens and reads space-delimited text, but I don't understand how it works. How does the file get opened without an "open" or "read" command? Is there a way to rewind back to the beginning of the file? I'm trying to create a dynamically allocated array, which I don't know how to do until after I've counted through the file for the number of scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does the file get opened without an "open" or "read" command?

The [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) constructor will open the file.

> Is there a way to rewind back to the beginning of the file?

Use [`seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). If the EOF has been reached then you need to call [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) before calling `seekg()`.

> I'm trying to create a dynamically allocated array

If permitted, you could use `std::vector` to store the text read which would avoid having to read the contents of the file twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. As I mentioned to the other responder, I have to use pointers and dynamically allocated arrays for this assignment. I'm going try using clear() and seekg().

Comment: Ok, thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to use clear() before using seekg(). This section of code is working with these functions.

Comment: No problem. If this answer resolved your problem you can accept the answer by the clicking the white tick to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The file is opened by the constructor of the `std::ifstream` class.

You can use `fin.seekg(std::ios::beg);` to rewind the file, but it would be better to e.g. use a `std::vector` or `std::list` where you can use `push_back()` to push new elements without needing to know the number of elements in advance.

However, since the homework apparently explicitly requires you to use manually allocated arrays and pointers, something like this will do the job:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream fin("text.txt");
  size_t n = 0;
  int i;
  for (; fin >> i; ++n);
  fin.clear();
  fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  int *scores = new int[n];
  std::istream_iterator<int> first(fin), last;
  std::copy(first, last, scores);

  std::copy(scores, scores+n, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << "\n";
  delete[] scores;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this homework assignment specifically requires me to use pointers and create a dynamically allocated array. Besides, my professor says the "vector" capability comes at the cost of considerable overhead.

Comment: Ok, if it is not allowed, then you can't use it. But in real world code, **please** use vector. The overhead is almost always negligible. Especially in this kind of initialisation code.

Comment: Also, file I/O is usually very slow, so using the vector might in reality be actually the faster option.